# Return a given number of matches regex

Tags: regex

I want a regex expression that only return the two first matches. In this string, the desired expression should only return 'Miles Teller' and 'J.K. Simmons' instead of all the matches 'Miles Teller', 'J.K. Simmons', 'Melissa Benoist'...

```
'name': 'Miles Teller', 'name': 'J.K. Simmons', 'order': 1, 129104,
 'name': 'Melissa Benoist', 'order': 2, 'profile_path':  970216,
 'name': 'Austin Stowell', 'order': 'gender': 2, 'id': 223012, 'name':
 'Jayson Blair', 'order': 4, 'profile_path':
```

So far I have tried `(?<='name': ')([^']*)` and playing around with `{2}`. But I can't find the right place for setting the number.

The example in regex101: https://regex101.com/r/FRN7ei/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using look behind or look ahead will give you all matches possible satisfying the regex.

For capturing only first two values of `name` attribute, you will need to get away from using look around based regex and instead use a simple regex containing groups. You can use this regex, which has two groups where each group captures the name you intend to capture and `.*` at the end of regex consumes remaining text to not leave any opportunity to capture any more names further.

```
'name': '([^']*)'.*?'name': '([^']*)'.*
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FRN7ei/3)**

**Edit:**

`.*` from the regex is not needed while not using global modifier in the regex. Thanks to [sln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557597/sln) for reminding me back, which I almost skipped my mind :)

Comment: But what if between the two names are any character. I mean what if the string start: 
`'name': 'Miles Teller', fooo 1223 foo 345 foo 3578  'name': 'J.K. Simmons', 'order': 1, 129104,` ?

Comment: @TitoSanz: Just change the regex to this `'name': '([^']*)'.*?'name': '([^']*)'.*` where it will allow any character between two names as less as possible. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/FRN7ei/3) Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly, I am not a regex expert, but now I am a little close! :)

Comment: @TitoSanz: Glad I could help :) Regex is actually great fun, the closer you get, the more you enjoy :)

Comment: @sln: Yes, you're correct. No need to use global modifier and hence `.*` in the regex. I've updated my post too. Thanks for reminding it :)

Comment: If it is used in a global match, `.*` only has context if dot not match newline. Otherwise, there will only be 1 match in global context, which makes global context useless in dot-all mode.

Answer (score 1):

Regexes follow leftmost match behavior, so could you explicitly request the first two names?

`/'name': '([^']+)', 'name': '([^']+)'/`?

On a side note, it probably be safer to parse the JSON and then do an array slice.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a valid dictionary/object, but assuming this is just a string that kind of looks like a dictionary/object, you can extract all names using something like what you had up there:

```
(?<='name': ')[^']+
```

then save this to a list or array, and get the first two matches with normal list indexing/slicing.